# Intel-Compiler fails C++14-check with `attribute "__malloc__" does not take arguments`

Tags: c++, c++14, intel, icc

I have the following code (intended to detect if the compiler supports C++14):

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

// Check the version language macro, but skip MSVC because
// MSVC reports 199711 even in MSVC 2017.
#if __cplusplus < 201402L && !defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
#error "insufficient support for C++14"
#endif

int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>(42);
    constexpr int max = std::max(0, 1);
    (void) ptr;
    (void) max;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling it with `g++` (version 11.2.1) and the line `g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test` it works fine. When compiling it with the intel compiler (version 2021.3.0 (gcc version 11.2.1 compatibility)) instead using `icpc -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test`, it fails with

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cwchar(44),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/postypes.h(40),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iosfwd(40),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr.h(52),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/memory(77),
                 from test.cpp(1):
/usr/include/wchar.h(155): error: attribute "__malloc__" does not take arguments
    __attribute_malloc__ __attr_dealloc_free;
                         ^

In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib(75),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algo.h(59),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm(62),
                 from test.cpp(2):
/usr/include/stdlib.h(565): error: attribute "__malloc__" does not take arguments
      __attr_dealloc_free;
      ^

In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib(75),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algo.h(59),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm(62),
                 from test.cpp(2):
/usr/include/stdlib.h(569): error: attribute "__malloc__" does not take arguments
       __THROW __attr_dealloc (reallocarray, 1);
               ^

In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib(75),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algo.h(59),
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm(62),
                 from test.cpp(2):
/usr/include/stdlib.h(797): error: attribute "__malloc__" does not take arguments
       __attr_dealloc_free __wur;
       ^

compilation aborted for test.cpp (code 2)
```

What exactly is going wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Short update: Looks as if CUDA is running into similar issues, and it might be related to glibc 2.34: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-11-5-samples-throw-multiple-error-attribute-malloc-does-not-take-arguments/192750/15

Comment: looks like that version of libstdc++ isn't compatible with that version of ICC.

Comment: GCC 11 allows `__malloc__` to take arguments. See https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/changes.html#c-family and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-malloc-function-attribute . Apparently ICC hasn't caught up.

Comment: @cpplearner: At least according to the compatibility level it should be able to support that, though...

Comment: @arc_lupus that generally refers to feature and flag compatibility. Builtins are a different monster all together as every different compiler has different builtins. While it would be best if stdlib implementations didn't use them sometimes they are de-facto required. Have you tried libc++?

Comment: @Mgetz: How can I use that together with icpc?

Comment: @arc_lupus try `-stdlib=libc++` IIRC. But don't be surprised if you run into issues there too.

Comment: @Mgetz: That did not help either, I still get the same errors

Comment: @arc_lupus what's your system GCC? Because it works fine on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/83PYoqGje)

Comment: I am running gcc version 11.2.1 20210816 @Mgetz

Comment: Use ICC with older GCC headers, or manually tweak how they define `__attribute_malloc__` (maybe with an `#ifdef` for ICC).

Answer (score 2):

Compiling and executing the shared code using icpc 2021.4 and it runs fine.

Used below command to compile the code.
icpc -std=c++14

Below are the environment details.

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-76-generic

For compatibility, Kindly refer the link for Intel® C++ Compiler Classic System Requirements

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/oneapi-c-compiler-system-requirements.html

Comment: I am using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, with GCC 11.2. This is not in the compatibility list, but is that an issue?

Comment: This question is about using ICPC on a system where the system GCC is GCC11, unlike on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system.  Yes obviously it would work to use an older system since `__attribute__((__malloc__))` taking an arg [is apparently new in GCC11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404834/intel-compiler-fails-c14-check-with-attribute-malloc-does-not-take-argu/69527120#comment122672950_69404834).  This answer seems to imply that switching distros would be necessary and the only solution, but doesn't even clearly say so.  And doesn't mention anything about the details of this compile error.

Comment: @PeterCordes: At least according to the documentation ICC should support GCC 11.2, but somehow it does not support handling __malloc__ with arguments...